# How can I read a file in a swift playground

Tags: swift

Im trying to read a text file using a Swift playground with the following

```
let dirs : String[]? =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as? String[]

if (dirs != nil) {
    let directories:String[] = dirs!;
    let dir = directories[0]; //documents directory
    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

    //read
    let content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
}
```

However this fails with no error. It seems the first line stops the playground from outputting anything below

Comment: `stringWithContentsOfFile` has an error parameter, check what it contains.

Comment: You should use conditional unwrapping - `if let directories = dirs {`. Saves a step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me. The only thing I changed was to be explicit about the file name (which is implied in your example) - perhaps you have a typo in the off-screen definition of the "file" variable?

```
let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as? [String]

let file = "trial.txt" // My change to your code - yours is presumably set off-screen
if let directories = dirs {
  let dir = directories[0]; //documents directory
  let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

  //read
  let content = NSString(contentsOfFile: path, usedEncoding: nil, error: nil)
  // works...
}
```

**Update Swift 4.2**

As @raistlin points out, this would now be

```
let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
              FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,
              FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask,
              true)
```

or, more tersely:

```
let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                .userDomainMask, true)
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this on a colleagues machine. It works, I am using Yosemite beta so guess that is my problem.

Comment: doh, problem was I had made an iOS playground.

Comment: Swift 4.2 version would be: 

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)`

Answer (score 81):

You can also put your file into your playground's resources. To do this: show Project Navigator with `CMD + 1`. Drag and drop your file into the resources folder. Then read the file:

On Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2:

```
var error: NSError?
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Input", withExtension: "txt")
let content = String(contentsOfURL: fileURL!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

On Xcode 7 and Swift 2:

```
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Input", withExtension: "txt")
let content = try String(contentsOfURL: fileURL!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

On Xcode 8 and Swift 3:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Input", withExtension: "txt")
let content = try String(contentsOf: fileURL!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

If the file has binary data, you can use `NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL!)` or `Data(contentsOf: fileURL!)` (for Swift 3).

Answer (score 40):

While the answer has been supplied for a quick fix, there is a better solution.

Each time the playground is opened it will be assigned a new container. This means using the normal directory structure you would have to copy the file you want into the new container every time.

Instead, inside the container there is a symbolic link to a *Shared Playground Data* directory (/Users/`UserName`/Documents/Shared Playground Data) which remains when reopening the playground, and can be accessed from multiple playgrounds.

You can use XCPlayground to access this shared folder.

```
import XCPlayground

let path = XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("foo.txt")
```

The official documentation can be found here: [XCPlayground Module Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/XCPlayground.html)

Cool post on how to organize this directory per-playground: [Swift, Playgrounds, and XCPlayground](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/12/12/swift-playgrounds-xcplayground/)

---

**UPDATE:** For swift 4.2 use [playgroundSharedDataDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundshareddatadirectory). Don't need to import anything.
Looks like:

```
let path = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file")
```

**Update for Swift 5:** you need to `import PlaygroundSupport` to be able to access the `playgroundSharedDataDirectory` global variable.

Comment: Great answer, awesome solution!
I had to create `~/Documents/Shared Plaground Data` but after that all worked as expected.
Thank you!

Comment: typo in above comment but it does the business. Create that folder in documents, drop whatever in, and it's available in XCPSharedDataDirectoryPath

Comment: `XCPSharedDataDirectoryPath` is deprecated.  It suggests to use `XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL`.

Comment: XCode 7.3. Created ``~/Documents/Shared Playground Data`` directory, copied my file there, and then used the following code in Playground:

    ``import XCPlayground`` at the top, and ``let path = XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myfile.txt")`` where I needed to open the file. Note that I was trying to use ``NSData(contentsOfFile:)`` but with above I just needed to switch to ``NSData(contentsOfURL:)``. Works like a charm!

Comment: Perfect Answer! Make sure to create the "Shared Playground Data" folder in "Documents" for it to work!

Comment: "For swift 4.2 use playgroundSharedDataDirectory. Don't need to import anything" -- you do need to import PlaygroundSupport (Swift 5 / Xcode 10.2)

Comment: Although this approach seems elegant. It is annoying is that we have to create `~/Documents/Shared Playground Data/ ` You want playground to work out of the box so maybe the bundle approach is better.

Comment: It seems that it "is not supported in Swift Playgrounds" anymore (Playgrounds 3.4.1)

Answer (score 32):

### 1. Access a file that is located in the `Resources` folder of your Playground

With Swift 3, `Bundle` has a method called [`url(forResource:withExtension:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1411540-url). `url(forResource:withExtension:)` has the following declaration:

```
func url(forResource name: String?, withExtension ext: String?) -> URL?
```

> Returns the file URL for the resource identified by the specified name and file extension.

You can use `url(forResource:withExtension:)` in order to read the content of a json file located in the `Resources` folder of an iOS or Mac Playground:

```
import Foundation

do {
    guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Data", withExtension: "json") else { fatalError() }
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

### 2. Access a file that is located in the `~/Documents/Shared Playground Data` folder of your computer

With Swift 3, `PlaygroundSupport` module provides a global constant called [`playgroundSharedDataDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/playgroundsupport/playgroundshareddatadirectory). `playgroundSharedDataDirectory` has the following declaration:

```
let playgroundSharedDataDirectory: URL
```

> The path to the directory containing data shared between all playgrounds.

You can use `playgroundSharedDataDirectory` in order to read the content of a json file located in the `~/Documents/Shared Playground Data` folder of your computer from an macOS playground:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

do {
    let fileUrl = PlaygroundSupport.playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Data.json")        
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 3 (Xcode 8)**

The code below works in both iOS and macOS playgrounds.  The text file ("MyText.txt" in this example) must be in the `Resources` directory of the playground.  *(Note: You may need to open the navigator window to see the directory structure of your playground.)*

```
import Foundation

if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"MyText", withExtension: "txt")
{
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(contents)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
} else {
    print("No such file URL.")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the .playground file.
2. Open Utility inspector, In the playground press opt-cmd-1 to open the File Inspector.      You should see the playground on the right. If you don't have it selected, press cmd-1 to open the Project Navigator and click on the playground file.
3. Under 'Resource Path' in Playground Settings choose 'Relative To Playground' and platform as OSX.

Comment: Try changing Platform in PlayGround setting to OSX , It works only for OSX.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the platform was the issue, but only seemed to work when created a new playground from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

On Mavericks with `Xcode 6.0.1` you can read using iOS platform too.

```
import UIKit
let dirs : [String]? =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as? [String]
let myDir = "/Shared Playground Data"

let file = "README.md" // My change to your code - yours is presumably set off-screen
if (dirs != nil) {
  let directories:[String] = dirs!;
  let dir = directories[0] + myDir; // iOS playground documents directory
  let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

  //read
  let content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
  // works...
  println(content!)
}
```

Remember, you need to create a directory called `"Shared Playground Data"` in your Documents directory. Im my case I used this command: `mkdir "/Users/joao_parana/Documents/Shared Playground Data"` and put there my file `README.md`

Answer (score 1):

String.stringWithContentsOfFile is DEPRECATED and doesn't work anymore with Xcode 6.1.1

Create your documentDirectoryUrl

```
let documentDirectoryUrl = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as NSURL
```

To make sure the file is located there you can use the finder command Go To Folder e copy paste the printed documentDirectoryUrl.path there

```
println(documentDirectoryUrl.path!)
// should look like this: /Users/userName/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.PLAYGROUNDFILENAME-5AF5B25D-D0D1-4B51-A297-00015EE97F13/Data/Documents
```

Just append the file name to the folder url as a path component

```
let fileNameUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("ReadMe.txt")
var fileOpenError:NSError?
```

Check if the file exists before attempting to open it

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileNameUrl.path!) {

    if let fileContent = String(contentsOfURL: fileNameUrl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &fileOpenError) {
        println(fileContent)        // prints ReadMe.txt contents if successful
    } else {
        if let fileOpenError = fileOpenError {
            println(fileOpenError)  // Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=XXX "The file “ReadMe.txt” couldn’t be opened because...."
        }
    }
} else {
    println("file not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to read a file with ease in playground and ended up just creating a `command line` app in Xcode. This seemed to work for me very well.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers, relying on "playgroundSharedDataDirectory" never works for me, especially if using an iOS playground.

```js
let documentsDirectoryShareURL = PlaygroundSupport.playgroundSharedDataDirectory.absoluteURL
let fileManager = FileManager()
try? fileManager.copyItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/rufus/Documents/Shared Playground Data/"), to: documentsDirectoryShareURL)
```

I just do the above now. I can populate my documents/shared folder, and it is just manually automatically copied to the playgrounds documents directory.

My code will not overwrite files that exist there. You could enhance this if you need it to look at file timestamps and then copy if necessary etc.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.7.1 - Xcode 14.1

```
func readFile() -> [String] {
    
    if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "txt") {
        do {
            let content = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            var x = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            x.removeAll { data in
                data.isEmpty
            }
            return x
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    return [String]()
   
}
//Usage:
let input = readFile()
```